# how to stop the execution of a cv2 program

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am currently workingon a project which requires body detection, so i created a file for it and when i tried to use it my main file but the body detection keeps on running and never stops making my rest of the program non executabale . I know it is because of the infinite for loop. But do i have any other ways where i could use in my main file

i have attached the body detection program below

kindly help

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time



mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mppose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mppose.Pose()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('open cv/squidgamee/3.mp4')
cap.set(3, 400)
cap.set(4, 800)
ptime =0
while True:
    
    succ, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = pose.process(imgRGB)
    #print(results.pose_landmarks)
    if results.pose_landmarks:
        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, mppose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
        lmlist= []
        if results.pose_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx ,  cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
                lmlist.append([id, cx, cy]) 

                cv2.circle(img, (lmlist[0][1], lmlist[0][2]), 15 , (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            print(lmlist[0])
    
    ctime = time.time()
    fps = 1/(ctime-ptime)
    ptime = ctime

    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, (255,255,0), 3)


    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    key= cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: You need to execute rest of your program inside of the loop.

Comment: Hi, you want to stop the image showing and do the next calculation? if so, you have to press 'q' when targeting 'image' windows. if you want to do more calculation while running, as @Amongalen said, you have to put it inside the while loop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the content in the file in function on a separate thread.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

def func():
    mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    mppose = mp.solutions.pose
    pose = mppose.Pose()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('open cv/squidgamee/3.mp4')
    cap.set(3, 400)
    cap.set(4, 800)
    ptime =0
    while True:
    
        succ, img = cap.read()
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = pose.process(imgRGB)
        if results.pose_landmarks:
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, mppose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            lmlist= []
            if results.pose_landmarks:
                for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                    h, w, c = img.shape
                    cx,  cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
                    lmlist.append([id, cx, cy]) 

                    cv2.circle(img, (lmlist[0][1], lmlist[0][2]), 15 , (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                print(lmlist[0])
    
        ctime = time.time()
        fps = 1/(ctime-ptime)
        ptime = ctime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, (255,255,0), 3)

        cv2.imshow("image", img)
        key= cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
```

Main:

```
import threading
from file import func
x = threading.Thread(target=func, args=())
x.start()
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much Ammar Aslam